# "not a valid identifier" error when running Teaspoon

Tags: teaspoon

When running teaspoon, I'm getting the following errors:

```
rake teaspoon
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:64790/teaspoon/default
sh: line 25: `BASH_FUNC_set_shell_label%%': not a valid identifier

Teaspoon running insight suite at http://127.0.0.1:64790/teaspoon/insight
sh: line 25: `BASH_FUNC_set_shell_label%%': not a valid identifier

Teaspoon running wb5 suite at http://127.0.0.1:64790/teaspoon/wb5
sh: line 25: `BASH_FUNC_set_shell_label%%': not a valid identifier
```

I haven't yet been able to identify which file's line 25 is the problem.

Comment: Apparently this has been caused by updating bash against the shellshocker vulnerability.  How to recover?

Comment: Update:  I installed Apple's fix for bash on Mavericks and now I"m getting this:

Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:49354/teaspoon/default
Error: ActionView::Template::Error: Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( teaspoon.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Following those instructions hasn't helped.